# Java accessing elements in an arraylist slower over time

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have some code, and I noticed that the progress of iterating through an ArrayList became drastically slower over time. The code that seems to be causing the problem is as below:

```
public boolean isWordOfficial(String word){
    return this.wordList.get(this.stringWordList.indexOf(word)).isWordOfficial();
}
```

Is there something about this code I don't know in terms of accessing the two arraylists?

Comment: What do you mean over time? Also, why are you using two ArrayLists for this?

Comment: please provide entire code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't exactly why, or by how much, your `ArrayList` performance is becoming too slow, but from a quick glance at your use case, you are doing the following operations:

- given a String `word`, look it up in `stringWordList`, and return the numerical index
- lookup the word in `wordList` contained at this index and return it

This pattern of usage would better be served by a `Map`, where the key would be the input `word`, possibly corresponding to an entry in `stringWordList`, and the output another word, from `wordList`.

A map lookup would be an `O(1)` operation, as compared to `O(N)` for the lookups in a list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, will look at implementing that. Based on my needs, I will likely have both of those arraylists, but will also create a Map for that specific function. I have a setup loading screen/alert, so I can just do it there.

Comment: I would have given you code for how to build the map, but the snippet you gave is not complete enough for anything I give to be meaningful.

Comment: That's fine, I know how to build a Map.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, the speed has actually improved drastically over my old method (the one before the one I posted about). Gonna see if I can implement a Map in general to speed up searching for other scenarios as well.

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

`this.stringWordList.indexOf` is O(N) and that is the cause of your issue. As N increases (you add words to the list) these operations take longer and longer.

To avoid this keep your list sorted and use [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).

This takes your complexity from O(n) to O(log(N)).